# MSpec and ReSharper Problem

Tags: resharper, mspec

I've got the latest mspec from the codebetter teamcity site and installed the Resharper5.1 runner as suggested.  The runner and the annotations show up fine in the resharper option dialogs.

Now even with the annotations library ticked I still get "field xxx is never used" warnings everywhere and when I ask resharper to run all tests in the solution it doesn't seem to find my specifications.

I have unblocked the dlls.

Using resharper 5.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Field xyz is never used" warnings only go away for classes that have the `Subject` attribute applied. If you don't use `Subject` you can work around the issue by disabling warning 169 in your spec projects.

Some questions about your issues with solution runs:

1. Did your enable MSpec under ReSharper | Options | Unit Testing?
2. Do specification runs for projects
   (as opposed to solution runs) work
   for you?
3. Can you start
   specifications by clicking the
   green/yellow icon in the gutter?
4. Does the Unit Text Explorer window
   correctly reflect the solution's
   contexts and specifications?

Comment: Adding the subject attribute worked for the warning thanks.  To answer your questions...

1. Yes it is enabled here
2. No, if I click the "Run Unit Tests" option I get a "No tests found in file" error
3. I don't get the gutter icons
4. It is completely empty

Comment: Are your context classes declared as `public`? You can try running your contexts with TestDriven.Net to see if it works with this runner. If it doesn't there's some larger problem. To use TD.Net, install it and drop the `MSpec.tdnet` file in the same folder where `MSpec.dll` resides.

Comment: Thanks Alexander, setting the class to public seems to have done the trick.